# Web2py and python 3

Tags: python-3.x, web2py

Does web2py function with python 3.3 or python 3.4? I have installed web2py but it cannot run with the python3.4 that I use.
I get an error after trying to run the 'web2py.exe - S welcome' that says, syntax error

Answer (score 14):

Currently, web2py only works with Python 2.6 - 2.7. Due to the promise of backward compatibility, web2py will not migrate to Python 3 only. However, work is underway on making web2py run under both Python 2 (specifically, 2.7) and Python 3 (specifically, >= 3.5).

UPDATE: As of the 2.15.1 release, web2py now supports both Python 2 and Python 3.